# Declare an Enum inline with a struct declaration

Tags: rust, syntax

I could have a structure like the following:

```rust
struct Example {
    state: State,
    properties: HashMap<String, String>,
}

enum State {
    a, b, c,
}
```

If the Example structure is the only user of the State enum, I think it would make sense to declare it in the struct:

```rust
struct Example {
    state: enum { a, b, c },
    properties: HashMap<String, String>,
}
```

Is there any valid syntax for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. There is no such syntax.

You can check the [Rust grammar for `struct`s](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/structs.html), the type of a field must be a [type expression](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types.html#type-expressions). Type expressions cannot create new types.